# Docker+Java -VSTS No such file or directory

Tags: java, docker, azure-devops, dockerfile, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to do continuous integration using VSTS for Java rest api.

I've added following lines for building Docker image:

FROM openjdk:8
ADD $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/docker-spring.jar docker-spring.jar
EXPOSE 8085
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","docker-spring.jar"]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm getting following error:
ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder946930284/SpringRest/target/docker-spring.jar: no such file or directory

/usr/local/bin/docker failed with return code: 1

I could see lot few references, still not able to correlate the issue exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you haven't supplied the path right. Make sure that your variable that has the path has the . for current directory, or / and the full path to the resources:

```
$(build.artifactstagingdirectory) = ./correct/relative/path/docker-spring.jar
```

or

```
$(build.artifactstagingdirectory) = /correct/full/path/path/docker-spring.jar<
```

Looking at your output I'd assume you're using "path/to/docker-spring.jar" which doesn't work.

EDIT: In your particular case you want to change the following line in the docker file:

What you have:

```
COPY /SpringRest/target/docker-spring.jar /usr/local/app/docker-spring.jar
```

What it should be:

```
COPY ./target/docker-spring.jar /usr/local/app/docker-spring.jar
```

Notice the little dot. This way it should work.

Comment: Let me check the above path issue. Thanks. Is it mandatory to create Docker.CI.Build.yaml to build using VSTS??

Comment: I am new to Devops. I dont have that much knowledge on the same.

Comment: I have given following as Dockerfile instruction    FROM openjdk:8
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/app
WORKDIR /usr/local/app
COPY /SpringRest/target/docker-spring.jar /usr/local/app/docker-spring.jar
EXPOSE 8085
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","docker-spring.jar"]     I am still getting following error:    COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder484497191/SpringRest/target/docker-spring.jar: no such file or directory

Comment: CI is pretty cool but not mandatory at all. Check the edit of my post for what should get it fixed.

Comment: Thanks Neekoy. I am trying it now. Hope the change will fix the issue.

Comment: Still no luck. I am getting same exception.

Comment: @Girish I think your Dockerfile is inside the SpringRest folder, looking at your shortcuts. I edited my post above, can you try it again with the COPY command at the end?

Comment: After adding above copy command, it started pointing to /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder290476507/target/docker-spring.jar: no such file or directory. why the /var/lib/tmp/docker-builder is getting appended to the given docker path

Comment: Thanks Neekoy!!!!. it is working now. I am able to build and push the image to Azure container resgitry using VSTS !!!

Comment: @Girish yup, basically when you see "/var/lib/docker/tmp/" being appended you most likely provided a path to a non-existent resource. Cheers :)